# Question about pronouns

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

If I wanted to say "If you want to play tennis but your parents don't let you do it, I can help", do I say "Si vous voulez jouer aux tennis mais que vos parents ne vous permettent pas le faire, je peux vous aider" or "Si vous voulez jouer aux tennis mais que vos parents ne vous permettent pas faire, je peux vous aider" (one has an extra le) or neither?

Comment: Au tennis (*au=à le*). And it *permettre **de** faire quelque chose*. About *le* it's you first choice, you need ***le*** (don't allow you to do **it**.)

Comment: I would leave out the "que": mais vos parents etc.

Comment: @Lambie No. That would be a poor idea. ***Que*** is grammatical here, omitting it is not.

Answer (score 1):

***De*** is mandatory between *permettre* and an infinitive. The right form is *ne vous permettent pas **de le** faire*.

A few comments:

- Despite its final *S*, the word tennis is singular here so that must be written ***au** tennis*, not *aux tennis* (you don't play "tennisses").
- This is addressed to a kid so the *vouvoiement* is unlikely.
- *Permettre de le faire* can be simplified to *le permettre*, *l'autoriser*, *être d'accord* or simply *vouloir*.

That leads to:

> Si tu veux jouer au tennis mais que tes parents veulent pas, je peux t'aider.

Comment: isn't it "...que tes parents NE veulent pas..." ?

Comment: @radouxju It is indeed in formal, written or "school teach" French. Talking to a kid, I would probably never say *que tes parents ne veulent pas*. It's partially similar to "your parents don't let you go" vs "your parents do not let you go". I might say *que tes parents n'veulent pas* though.